# php + mysql развернуть даты в колонках, показатели в строках, данные на пересечении

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Не могу сообразить (возможно вопрос простой, но я уперся в него) как правильно оформить вывод данных из MYSQL таблицы вида:
id, timestamp, metric, value
в таблицу где колонки - это даты (timestamp), строки это показатели (metric), их пересечение, это собственно данные (value) на эту дату, по этому показателю?
Концептуально не могу понять как делать выборку и к чему преобразовывать (думал двухмерный массив, т.к. могут быть даты, где не будет у показателя данных)

Comment: Это называется PIVOT и в MySQL не поддерживается. Или пиши хранимую процедуру, или (лучше) используй возможности средства построения отчётов на клиенте.

Comment: а если выбрать одномерным массивом, а потом уже средствами php в двухмерный перевести? Только вопрос в быстродействии и качестве?

Comment: Получаете данные и на стороне php уже обработайте как надо. У меня такого в проектах много, если нельзя сделать на стороне БД.

Comment: Ну... в общем да. Нет, можно и на стороне MySQL выполнить такое преобразование, конечно (даже, если позарез надо, могу дать готовую процедуру - при условии, что Вы пообещаете досконально в ней разобраться) - но надо понимать, что при этом итоговая выборка имеет динамическую структуру, что нереляционно и может вызвать проблемы на стороне клиента.

Comment: @Akina можете натолкнуть методологически на правильный вариант преобразования одномерного массива в двухмерный в php? И да, структура динамическая, думаю процедурой не совсем верно будет сделать и это не единственная задача такого плана, хочется понять как в разным вариантах её решать.

Comment: PHP для меня - тёмный лес. То есть могу, но долго и неоптимально. Так что лучше пусть кто-то ещё...

Comment: Ну т.е. делаем select id, timestamp, metric, value из бд, формируем шаблонный массив со всем возможными timestamp (грубо, т.к. буду округлять до date) и всем возможными metric
и уже по нему проходиться и забивать данными value?